AdaptiveCard disappears randomly on a MSTEAMS message extension bot
We have a message extension bot for MSTeams written in nest.js which is implemented like the following sample:
import {
    CloudAdapter,
    CardFactory,
    MessagingExtensionAction,
    MessagingExtensionActionResponse,
    TeamsActivityHandler,
    TurnContext
} from 'botbuilder';

@Controller()
export class BotController {

    @Post(['/api/messages'])
    public async messageExtensionCall(
        @I18n() i18n: I18nContext,
        @Req() req: Request,
        @Res() res: Response
    ): Promise<void> {
        const botFrameworkAuthentication = ...;
        const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication);

        await adapter.process(req, res, async (context) => {
            const actionId = context.activity.value.commandId;
            switch (actionId) {
                case 'Some_Action':
                    await new ActionHandler().run(context);
                    break;
                default:
                    Logger.warn(`Unsupported action ${actionId}`);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

export class ActionHandler extends TeamsActivityHandler {

    public override async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(
        context: TurnContext
    ): Promise<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> {
        return {
            task: {
                type: 'continue',
                value: {
                    title: 'A title',
                    url: 'target-url',
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 600
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public override async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction(
        context: TurnContext,
        action: MessagingExtensionAction
    ): Promise<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> {
        try {
            const response: MessagingExtensionActionResponse = {};
            const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
                type: 'AdaptiveCard',
                version: '1.5'
            });
    
            response.composeExtension = {
                type: 'result',
                attachmentLayout: 'list',
                attachments: [card]
            };
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            Logger.error('Cannot create submit action response.', error);
            return {};
        }
    }
}

The problem is that the resulting card disappears randomly in the input field of MSTeams client but the correct card is visible a few moments. After it disappears the user can't post the card into the chat cannel.
Mostly the second try to create the card works well.
There are no errors thrown at any point neither in nest.js server nor in browser dev console.
Edit: We investigated the issue even further and were able to mitigate the issue.
If you pin the message extension app, the adaptive card is always successfully sent to the input chat and does not disappear. If it is used over another way then the described behaviour occurs.
Does anyone experianced a similar problem and have any ideas why this happens?

Are you facing this issue in New Teams? Can you also verify that the card JSON is correctly formatted and adheres to the Adaptive Card schema?

Can you also share the repro steps?
